# How to detect when item half visible in listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapterview

[image]I am using a custom HorizontalListView having one item(Image) visible at a time. I need when i scroll through the list, a toast message should print when new visible item places in the half.
Means i want to print the name of item when it showing.
i have all item's name in an array.

As u can see in pic, current item showing is Glass, and it will scroll to the half of screen, i want to change the name above, i will change it, but **My Question Is: How to detect that, the new item places in half.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem solved. Firstly i get child item position from my listView, and then find item's x coordinate value,

```
int xCoordinate = listView.getChiledAt(position).getLeft();
```

and then make a condition in the onScroll(); method that

```
if(xCoordinate < screenWidth/2){
    textViewProduct.setText(productArray[position]);
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,productArray[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```